# How to convert these numbers?

Tags: binary

I am trying to understand number systems binary and decimal number systems. 
How can I convert the following numbers using the least amount of digits?

> 1. $(47)\text{base}-10$ to signed binary.
> 2. $(-27)\text{base}-10$ to signed and binary magnitude
> 3. $(213)\text{base}-16$ to a 10 base number

Here are my attemps:

1. $00101111$
2. $10011011$ (or 2's complement: $11100101$)
3. $531$

Am I heading right?

Comment: Where is your try, where are the examples...?

Answer (score 1):

These are all correct.  For 2, the first is correct according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign-magnitude#Sign-and-magnitude_method).  Twos' complement is different, which you have also done correctly.